# How to implements app models (class) in vendor package class?

Tags: php, laravel, package, vendor

How could I use another class in my vendor packages?
I want to implements "Searchable" & "Viewable" and add my Seo morphOne relation to a package like [Rinvex\Categorizable](https://github.com/rinvex/laravel-categories), how can I do this without adding codes in to this package {from outside of vendor package}??

Comment: Add it into dependency in `composer.json` file. If it is not already in project that uses your package it will be pulled in (vendor directory).

Comment: would you show me an example? @Tpojka

Comment: Include `rinvex/laravel-categories` in list of dependencies in `composer.json` file of your packege. Also, you have to mention in installation steps what has to be done in order that `rinvex/laravel-categories` installation steps must finish first.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to extend class from package that you need and add relation there.
Like that:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Product;
use Spatie\Searchable\Searchable;
use CyrildeWit\EloquentViewable\Contracts\Viewable;
use Rinvex\Categories\Models\Category as RinvexCategory;

class Category extends RinvexCategory implements Searchable, Viewable
{
    // Add relactions, override RinvexCategory methods or anything that you need :)
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

And use `App\Models\Category` in you other code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a model in your app and extends the package(vendor) model. Then define anything you want, add new traits or you can override methods.
You can use your model instead of the one provided by the package.

for example:

```php
use Rinvex\Categories\Models\Category;

class MyModel extends Category {

  use MyExampleTraits, SearchableTraits;

  // You can add a new column to the table by publishing package migrations
 // or you can create a new migration to add your new columns
 
  public function seo() {
      return $this->morphOne(Seo::class, 'seoable');
  }
}
```

*Note that the above code is just for a demonstration to give you hint. I hope you find it helpful.*